# Not Sure If Session Is Initiated Using Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to use Facebook's PHP SDK. The code that makes a call to Facebook to retrieve user's information is saved in a file called fbcall.php. The fbcall.php page is called through an href link from another page called index.php

The Entire Code (index.php):

```
<?php
echo "<a href=\"fbcall.php\">Login Here</a>";
?>
```

Index.php is also my FacebookRedirectLoginHelper redirect url.

The question I have is that I'm not seeing an output for the following statement in the fbcall.php file and I'm not sure why?

```
echo "Name: " . $user_profile->getName();
```

I get the sense that my sessions isn't initiated but I'm sure how to validate this. And if it isn't initiated then I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong considering I'm following Facebook's guidelines here (or atleast I think I am).

The Entire Code (fbcall.php):

```
<?php
session_start();
// Make sure to load the Facebook SDK for PHP via composer or manually

require_once 'autoload.php';

//require 'functions.php';  
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;


// add other classes you plan to use, e.g.:
// use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
// use Facebook\GraphUser;
// use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('AM USING MY APP ID HERE','AM USING MY SECRET KEY HERE');


$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://localhost/facebook/index.php');
$params = array('email','public_profile', 'user_status', 'user_friends');
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($params);

try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
  // var_dump($session);
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
}
if (isset($session)) {
  var_dump($session);
}
else
{
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
  header("location:".$loginUrl);
  exit;
}


$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

if(isset($session)) {
  try {
    $user_profile = (new FacebookRequest(
      $session, 'GET', '/me'
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
    echo "Name: " . $user_profile->getName();
  } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
    echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
    echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();
  }   
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the user grant your permissions, he/she will be redirected to `index.php` (because of your `redirect_uri`).

So there is two solutions:
- change you're `redirect_uri` to be `fbcall.php`
- move all `fbcall.php` logic to `index.php`, and change `header("location:".$loginUrl);` by `echo "<a href=\"$loginUrl\">Login Here</a>";`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

If I change it to the first potential solution, I get stuck in infinite redirects and the browser eventually throws an error.

As for the second one it first takes me to face book's login page automatically and then does the same as the first solution (infinite redirects).

Comment: Can you add a `var_dump()` in each `catch`?

Comment: Tried vardump() in each catch. Got no output.

Also noticed that when I hardcode User Token like this

    $session = new FacebookSession('User Token');

the session initiates and i get an output for the App Developer Name.

Comment: I mean `var_dump($ex);`

Comment: yea nothing. So i know for a fact that the session isn't initiating. Probably getting NULL from Facebook. I just don't know why.